Why does the ScrollView detect multiple direct childs?
I'm trying to retrieve lost data from my Firebase and then implement some basic crud so that I can barely pass this paper. Here are the source codes that I'm using:
activity_admin_main.xml: this is the UI for the functions, I have yet to add the buttons for the crud methods mentioned before, and this is only an attempt to list the documents in a Firebase collection called "course"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/appbackground"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.056"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/appicon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/edit_text_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
        android:text="tvName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="330sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/edit_text_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.259"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/button_background_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_admin_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

fragment_course.xml: this is the xml of the code with a problem, there are two other fragment xmls, but those are still empty for now, and share similar crud functions, so I could just modify the complete code that does function well
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.courses.CourseFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription=" ">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- TextViews dynamically added here -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

AdminMain.kt: this is the Kotlin file for the whole navigation view, and the function I used to retrieve the name value from my firestore, not much to see here... I think
package com.example.assignment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.assignment.databinding.ActivityAdminMainBinding
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class AdminMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAdminMainBinding
    lateinit var tvNameObj: TextView
    lateinit var tvEmailObj: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityAdminMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val db = Firebase.firestore
        tvNameObj = findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        tvEmailObj = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_admin_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_course, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        var name = ""
        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
        if (email != null) {
            db.collection("admin")
                .whereEqualTo("email", email)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    if (!documents.isEmpty) {
                        val document = documents.documents[0]
                        name = document.getString("name").toString()
                        if (name != "") {
                            tvNameObj.text = name
                            tvEmailObj.text = email
                            Log.i("Successful", "Name retrieved successfully")
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle case where no document is found
                        Log.w("Not found", "Name not found")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    // Handle any errors here
                    Log.wtf("WTF", "What The Fxxk happened!?", exception)
                }
        }
    }
}

And finally, CourseFragment.kt, this is where the problem occurred, for now I'm only attempting to retrieve and display the data from Firebase and store them in textViews that will be stored in a linear layout, then store the linear layout in the scrollView so that it only contain one direct child.
package com.example.assignment.ui.courses

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.assignment.databinding.FragmentCourseBinding
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class CourseFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCourseBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val courseViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentCourseBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val scrollView: ScrollView = binding.scrollView
        val linearLayout: LinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        // Fetch data from Firestore
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        db.collection("course")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    // Create a TextView for each document
                    val textView = TextView(context)
                    textView.text = document.data.toString()

                    // Add the TextView to the LinearLayout
                    linearLayout.addView(textView)
                }
                // Add the LinearLayout to the ScrollView
                scrollView.addView(linearLayout)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("Not Found", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

So my problem is that Android Studio keeps returning this error about having more than 1 child, and I have tried moving scrollView.addView(linearLayout) to other lines but still to no avail. What can I try next?
And here's the fatal error message:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.assignment, PID: 21660
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:261)
at com.example.assignment.ui.courses.CourseFragment$onCreateView$1.invoke(CourseFragment.kt:54)
at com.example.assignment.ui.courses.CourseFragment$onCreateView$1.invoke(CourseFragment.kt:44)
at com.example.assignment.ui.courses.CourseFragment.onCreateView$lambda$0(CourseFragment.kt:44)
at com.example.assignment.ui.courses.CourseFragment.$r8$lambda$k4oKZ0mPYZVACvyeiTV-bMatA7Q(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.assignment.ui.courses.CourseFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)


You are adding a new LinearLayout in your fragment instead of using the one already present in your XML.
The correct fragment code should be:
class CourseFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentCourseBinding? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val courseViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = FragmentCourseBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val scrollView: ScrollView = binding.scrollView
    val linearLayout: LinearLayout = binding.containerLayout

    // Fetch data from Firestore
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    db.collection("course")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                // Create a TextView for each document
                val textView = TextView(context)
                textView.text = document.data.toString()

                // Add the TextView to the LinearLayout
                linearLayout.addView(textView)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("Not Found", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }

    return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

First thing get the correct LinearLayout using binding
val linearLayout: LinearLayout = binding.containerLayout

Remove scrollView.addView(linearLayout), you already have that in your XML.

I see, so I actually did add more than 1 linear layouts into the scrollview.. that worked well, thank you!

Exactly, you were creating a new LinearLayout and adding it to the ScrollView, that only accepts 1 and only 1 child.
